# Tricky question about binomial expansions.

Tags: combinatorics

State the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$

So I can do this $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i}x^i$$

Then given $n=2k$ is even. Derive an expression for

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2k} (-1)^i{2k\choose i}$$ this is where I am stuck cause this is the same as above with $x=-1$ so is the answer just 
$$(1+(-1))^{2k}=\sum_{i=0}^{2k} {2k\choose i}(-1)^i=0^{2k}=0 ~\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  It actually doesn't even require $n$ to be even...

Comment: Its OK, is because the combinatorial numbers are simetryc in the mid, and you alternate the sign

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's only correct as long as $k>0$.

Comment: Yeah I meant $\mathbb{N}$ ignore that bit.

Answer (score 0):

A combinatorial interpretation: you are correct in thinking that the sum is zero. One way to express this is that the number of subsets of odd cardinality of an $n$ element set is the same as the number of subsets of even cardinality of an $n$ element set. Indeed we can put these in bijection by taking the symmetric difference of a set with $\{1\}$, i.e. 
$$
A\mapsto A\triangle \{1\}.
$$